# Is there a best practice for where to log when running multiple instances of an application with Docker?

Tags: logging, docker

I am trying to create an application that will be run on multiple Docker instances on multiple machines. Since  my containers will be running `nginx` as their command, `docker logs` would show the output of nginx logs, which is fine. However, that begs the question: where should my application log?

The options I have thought about are the following.

### Log on the host file system

As far as I can tell, to be able to identify which Docker container has written to the log, I must create something like `/var/logs/myapplication`, and create a folder for each container, and tell my application inside the container to write into that directory. For example, I would have to create `/var/logs/myapplication/instance-1` and mount that as a volume inside my Docker container.

The problem in this approach is that it's hard to collect logs. I will have to ssh to different machines, go in the `/var/logs/myapplication` directory of each machine and get the logs out to read them. It's perfectly fine when I know there's a question, but confusing when I am trying to monitor the whole system.

### Logging in the database

In this method, all Docker containers will write to a database, and one of the columns of the database will be `container_name` so that I can filter logs based on container name.

The problem with this approach is that I haven't ever used a database for keeping logs, and I'm not really sure if they are meant to be used like this.

### Back to the original question

So my question is, is there a proven best-practice for logging when you have multiple machines with multiple containers on each?

Comment: Possibly you should look into something like this which I think would be preferable to using a standard database: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2015/04/27/automating-docker-logging-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana-and-logspout/

I don't know enough about logstash/similar solutions to recommend one though which is why I haven't posted an answer.